# Has the E-11 blaster ever seen action in the Star Wars movies with its folding three-position stock extended?

Tags: star-wars, blasters

The other day, while posing one of my 3.75 inches Imperial Stormtrooper action figures, I noticed that its E-11 had a real folding stock. That made me think why -in the *Star Wars* movies- all the wielders of E-11 blaster rifles always grab them with one hand or while using two hands use the folding three-position stock as a foregrip but never with the stock unfolded. According to the canon/Legends, the E-11 can be converted into a full-length rifle with just unfolding (extending) the stock. In case that I have missed it, I ask if someone has seen in the *Star Wars* movies an E-11 blaster in action with its folding three-position stock extended?

[image: E-11 schematics]

Comment: Movies, no. Other canon properties (https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/E-11_blaster_rifle#Appearances) yes, probably.

Comment: maybe they should have used it as such : <insert accuracy joke here>